# Sypder 5.0.1 fails to load

Tags: python, pyqt, spyder

when launching Spyder, it shows the loading screen but eventually it stops and I get the following error message. Any ideas?

```
No QCoreApplication instance found. Application patches not applied. You have to call load_stylesheet function after instantiation of QApplication to take effect. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hagymasbab/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 2161, in create_window
    main.setup()
  File "/home/hagymasbab/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 903, in setup
    plugin_instance = plugin_class(self, configuration=CONF)
  File "/home/hagymasbab/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/api/plugins.py", line 1405, in __init__
    super().__init__(parent, configuration=configuration)
  File "/home/hagymasbab/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/api/plugins.py", line 826, in __init__
    self._container = container = self.CONTAINER_CLASS(
  File "/home/hagymasbab/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/plugins/console/widgets/main_widget.py", line 122, in __init__
    self.shell = InternalShell(  # TODO: Move to use SpyderWidgetMixin?
  File "/home/hagymasbab/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/plugins/console/widgets/internalshell.py", line 153, in __init__
    super().__init__(parent, get_conf_path('history_internal.py'),
  File "/home/hagymasbab/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/plugins/console/widgets/shell.py", line 665, in __init__
    ShellBaseWidget.__init__(self, parent, history_filename,
  File "/home/hagymasbab/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/plugins/console/widgets/shell.py", line 75, in __init__
    self.history = self.load_history()
  File "/home/hagymasbab/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/plugins/console/widgets/shell.py", line 503, in load_history
    if rawhistory[1] != self.INITHISTORY[1]:
IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hagymasbab/.local/bin/spyder", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/hagymasbab/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 213, in main
    mainwindow.main(options, args)
  File "/home/hagymasbab/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 2311, in main
    mainwindow = create_window(app, splash, options, args)
  File "/home/hagymasbab/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 2163, in create_window
    if main.console is not None:
  File "/home/hagymasbab/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 1180, in __getattr__
    return self.get_plugin(self._INTERNAL_PLUGINS_MAPPING[attr])
  File "/home/hagymasbab/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 169, in get_plugin
    raise SpyderAPIError(
spyder.api.exceptions.SpyderAPIError: Plugin "internal_console" not found!
```

Versions: Spyder: 5.0.1, pyqt5: 5.12.3

Please mind that this is NOT the latest version of pyqt5. However, if I upgrade it to 5.15.4, Spyder won't even start loading, it dies with this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 22, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
ImportError: libQt5QuickWidgets.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hagymasbab/.local/bin/spyder", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/hagymasbab/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 209, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/home/hagymasbab/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 60, in <module>
    from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets  # analysis:ignore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 26, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage as QWebEnginePage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets'
```

I'm using the latest version of qtpy (1.9.0).

EDIT:
Here is the output of the ldd command:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd139c9000)
libQt5Quick.so.5 => /home/hagymasbab/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5 (0x00007f72ed4b6000)
libQt5QmlModels.so.5 => /home/hagymasbab/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/libQt5QmlModels.so.5 (0x00007f72ed236000)
libQt5Qml.so.5 => /home/hagymasbab/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5 (0x00007f72ecbba000)
libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /home/hagymasbab/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f72ec358000)
libQt5Gui.so.5 => /home/hagymasbab/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f72eba27000)
libQt5Network.so.5 => /home/hagymasbab/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007f72eb677000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => /home/hagymasbab/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f72eae81000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f72eae36000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f72eadaf000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f72eabe2000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f72eaa9e000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f72eaa82000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f72ea8bd000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f72ea8b2000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f72ea895000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f72ea88f000)
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f72ea83a000)
libicui18n.so.56 => /home/hagymasbab/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/libicui18n.so.56 (0x00007f72ea3a1000)
libicuuc.so.56 => /home/hagymasbab/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/libicuuc.so.56 (0x00007f72e9fe9000)
libicudata.so.56 => /home/hagymasbab/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/libicudata.so.56 (0x00007f72e8606000)
libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f72e8601000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f72e84d0000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f72ede01000)
libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007f72e8418000)
libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007f72e83e4000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f72e830a000)
libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f72e82da000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f72e82d4000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f72e82c3000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f72e8250000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f72e810d000)
libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f72e8106000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f72e80ec000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f72e80bf000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f72e80ba000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f72e7eb4000)
libbsd.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f72e7e9d000)
libmd.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmd.so.0 (0x00007f72e7e90000)
```

Comment: Install PyQtWebEngine: https://pypi.org/project/PyQtWebEngine/

Comment: I already had version 5.12.3 installed. Now, if I upgrade it to the latest, spyder complains that it requires version < 5.13.

Comment: okay, what is your OS?

Comment: execute: `sudo apt install mlocate` `sudo updatedb` `locate libQt5QuickWidgets.so.5`, what is the output?

Comment: What do you get when you run the above command?

Comment: OS: Debian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid
outputs:
/home/hagymasbab/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/libQt5QuickWidgets.so.5
/home/hagymasbab/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/libQt5QuickWidgets.so.5

Comment: what is the output of `ldd /home/hagymasbab/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/libQt5QuickWidgets.so.5`?

Comment: execute `sudo apt-get install libxcursor-dev libxcomposite-dev libxdamage-dev libxrandr-dev libxtst-dev libxss-dev libdbus-1-dev libevent-dev libfontconfig1-dev libcap-dev libpulse-dev libudev-dev libpci-dev libnss3-dev libasound2-dev libegl1-mesa-dev gperf bison nodejs`

Comment: Done! See output below, it was too long to post it here.

Comment: 1) You should not publish it as an answer but it must be an edition of your post, 2) Did you get that before or after executing the command of my previous comment?

Comment: Noted! I've got it before installing.

Comment: After executing that command do you get the same error?

Comment: The error is the same, except for the adresses in the parenthesis.

Answer (score 5):

Problem solved! After issuing

```
spyder --reset
```

it loads again flawlessly. Still no idea, why...

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Sorry, the problem with Spyder (not the PyQtWebEngine one) was related to some changes we did in Spyder that required a reset.